# Strange Encoding on HTTP GET response in Qt

Tags: html, c++, qt, get

I am trying to simulate webpage activity through Qt (5.8) using QNetworkAccessManager. I have been using the FireBug plugin of Firefox to analyze each Get/Post request, copying the appropriate headers. On my initial GET request, I get a QNetworkReply object. I have inspected all of the headers, and it is the corrent response. However, when I try and read the data, I get a strange format. When viewing this packet in Wireshark, the HTML response shows up as it does in FireBug, something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />...
```

However, when I am reading my response to a QByteArray, the debugger says that this variable is:

```
\037\213\010\000\000\000\000\000\000\003µW[SÛ8\024~Æ¿BÕÌNàÁv\234\033\t$Ù\013\224¶;)0\020¦»O...
```

and when saving this QByteArray to a text file, it looks like this:

```
‹      µW[SÛ8~Æ¿BÕÌNàÁvœ    $Ù”¶;)0¦»OÙ–mQÙr%™Àîìß#_s-Ýay òÑ¹|
ç*É²¦ïŽÏŽ–ž¿G‰N9:¿úmñéaÛu¿ô\÷xyŒþø¸ü¼@žÓEKI2Å4á®ûþ#î­õlÝÚuBâ¹5-
•Þ¦<S3œh¸îz½vÖ}GÈØõ&“I%
Ó'Y<Ã4Ãh³2:(    çÖÎ4¥š £Ä¦ß
v3ÃG"Ó4Óöò.§Õ×kz«]£ô    ‘ŠêÙÕòÄcä¾¨ÆØ,HÜVe <-Dos&©jñÚÞs¼¹$qJZ¬™°$
´-‘”Î0)t"d‹õ3‘šeè#¹áD?æD~'Yœè–
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I feel like it is an encoding issue. My code looks like:

```
void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QByteArray getResponse = reply->readAll();
        QList<QNetworkReply::RawHeaderPair> headers = reply->rawHeaderPairs();
        output(QString(getResponse));
        QFile file("C:/Users/lrmlrm97/Desktop/Response.txt");
        if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++)
            {
                file.write(headers.at(i).first + ": " + headers.at(i).second);
                file.write("\r\n");
            }
            file.write("\r\n\r\n");
            file.write(getResponse);
            file.write("\r\n\r\n");
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks!

Lucas

Comment: Use  QTextDocument

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. One of the headers I was sending was

```
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

which was causing the response to be compressed. Once I removed this line, everything worked perfectly.